# Most elegant way to add a different object from vector in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I have a Vector containing `x`. What is the most elegant way to get the values of the list as an `Object[]` and add an `y` element to the end of it?

`x` and `y` are not of the same class or so.

The obvious solution would be to make a new `Object[]` with the size of the `Vector` + 1. Then iterate over it and add each `x`, and then add `y` at the end.

Also,

```
Object[] objectArray = vector.toArray();
```

Would make the `objectArray` shrink by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector vector= new Vector();
vector.add(x);

Vector temp = new Vector(vector);
temp.add(y);
Object[] objectArray = temp.toArray();
```

(If i understand right the Q ...)

Comment: could you illustrate this by providing a complete snippet of code.its quite confusing ,I have 2 questions for you 1>I dont see `x` added anywhere in the vector as the OP as pointed out.2>where are you doing this part as well `The most elegant way to get the values of the list as an Object[]`.Could you provide the complete functioning snippet.

Comment: @Deepak : the snippet is complete. The first line copies all the elements (X instances) in a new temp vector. The second line adds an y at the end of the temp vector, and the third line transforms the temp vector, containing x and y, into an array. Two array copies are thus made which I find not so elegant, but YMMV.

Comment: what is `vector` in `Vector temp = new Vector(vector);` can you tell me from where `(vector)` is getting populated.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object[] result = new Object[vector.size() + 1];
result = vector.toArray(result);
result[result.length - 1] = y;
```

This solution doesn't need a temp vector, and doesn't modify the original vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector.add(myY);
Object[] arr = vector.toArray();
vector.remove(vector.size()-1);
```

And you have to synchronize on vector if you don't want any suprise in case you are multi-threaded:

```
  synchronized (vector) {
    vector.add(myY);
    Object[] arr = vector.toArray();
    vector.remove(vector.size()-1);
  }
```